Generate Native Query with JOOQ and Map with Hibernate
Is it possible to generate a native query with jooq and use hibernate to do the mapping? I am generating the exact same sql that hibernate shows with print-sql: true, but am still getting org.hibernate.loader.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
// first see what hibernate prints for the hql query
val hql = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Parent p JOIN FETCH p.children WHERE p.id = ?1", Parent::class.java)

// shows
// select ce1_0.id, <other columns>, ce2_0.id, <other columns> from parent ce1_0 join children ce2_0 on ce1_0.id=ce2_0.parent_id where ce1_0.id=?


Now try and run the same query using a native query
// copy and paste exact query output that gets logged from HQL above
val query = em.createNativeQuery(copiedSql, Parent::class.java)

Running the above gives you the NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException
I originally tried this with jooq generation as well, but got the same error
val ce0 = Parents.PARENTS.`as`("ce1_0")
val ce1 = Children.CHILDREN.`as`("ce2_0")

val jooqQuery = 
  dsl.select(*ce0.fields(), *ce1.fields())
  .from(ce0)
  .join(ce1)
  .on(ce0.ID.eq(ce1.ID))
  .where(ce0.ID.eq(id))

// gives same error as above
val query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(jooqQuery.sql, Parent::class.java)


This doesn't answer your question, but it's always worth pointing out that executing queries with jOOQ directly has tons of benefit, just in case there's some room for how you can map stuff.

@LukasEder I want to but I need the mapping capabilities - I am handling GraphQL queries so the object graph can be arbitrarily nested

Also, the database is multiple terabytes so I think the json aggregation approach of the multiset operator in jooq might not be performant

jOOQ has a utility to nest arbitrary hierarchies in client code. But anyway, that's not the question here, I don't know Hibernate well enough to help with that particular exception, I'm afraid. Perhaps you can use a @SqlResultSetMapping to help you with this particular task?
